# Check for access status of ACAccount?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, acaccount, acaccountstore

There's a method exists which allows the user to grant access to a social account:

```
- (void)requestAccessToAccountsWithType:(ACAccountType *)accountType options:(NSDictionary *)options completion:(ACAccountStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler)completion
```

I invoke this early on in my app, but there is a part of my app that's designed to work without any user interaction, and in the scenario that the user revoked access at one point, I don't want them to be asked to evoke permissions at this point. The method is required to begin using an account, however. Is there a way to check what the access status of an account is, similar to how there is with location.